# Bootstrap column height issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have an issue in Bootstrap grid system. How can I fix this?
**I want it like the *Google plus grid system***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fYy7.png

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:50px'>
        hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:150px'>
        hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:100px'>
        hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:20px'>
        hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:50px'>
        hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:50px'>
        hello
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 panel' style='height:50px'>
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arammarm/99xwmyqa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get a grid system like that. It will look like table rows. What you want are two columns with the panels inside them.

Like this here:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
        <div class="panel" style='height:50px'>hello</div>
        <div class="panel" style='height:150px'>hello</div>
        <div class="panel" style='height:50px'>hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
        <div class="panel" style='height:150px'>hello</div>
        <div class="panel" style='height:50px'>hello</div>
        <div class="panel" style='height:150px'>hello</div>
    </div>    
    
</div>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Maege85/ttn4mkgk/)

Comment: Thanks for answering me .        It's not possible.. all panels are coming in the loop i want same style for all looped divs.

Comment: You could try something with flexbox like on bootply [Flexbox with col-6](http://www.bootply.com/qof7bxKmBp)